# AWS Lambda Java Error: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, gradle, aws-lambda

I'm getting this error when trying to test/invoke my AWS Lambda:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Class not found: com.schema.migration.handler.PgSchemaMigrationHandler",
  "errorType": "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"
}
```

I created the function with handler: `com.schema.migration.handler.PgSchemaMigrationHandler`
. This is my zip directory that I'm using to create my function:
[image]

My PgSchemaMigrationHandler.class:

```
   package com.schema.migration.handler;
   ...
   public class PgSchemaMigrationHandler implements RequestHandler<Map<String, Object>, Object> {

       //handler code
   }
```

I have the AWS dependencies in my build.gradle and also have this to build the zip:

```
distributions {
main {
    contents {
        from 'src/main/java'
        from 'src/main/resources'
        exclude("**/bifrost-schema-schema-migration-1.0.null.jar")
    }
}

distZip{
    dependsOn compileJava
}
```

Any ideas on why AWS can't find my class?

Comment: This looks like a packaging issue.  Is your build.gradle based on one of the [Java samples for Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-samples.html)?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too sure what you mean (This is my first time trying to use Lambda). My build.gradle is just AWS dependencies, java and spring boot plugins, and what I have above

Answer (score 0):

So far what I learned is AWS is not very Java friendly. But it works, I had issues earlier adding dependency jars with my package. I had built an uber jar with all the dependencies attached to it.

Here is how you can do it using gradle - https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/blob/master/sample-apps/blank-java/build.gradle